# IEEE 754 Addition of two 32-bit floating point numbers (-1 and 2^(-50) )

Tags: c++, floating-point, addition, ieee-754

Consider the following piece of C++ Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout.precision(1000000000);
    
    float a,b,c;
    
    a = 1;
    b = -1;
    c = pow(2, -50);
    
    cout << "a = " << a << endl;
    cout << "b = " << b << endl;
    cout << "c = " << c << endl;
    
    float ab = a + b;
    float bc = b + c;
    float abc = ab + c;
    float bca = bc + a;
    
    cout << "a + b = " << ab << endl;
    cout << "b + c = " << bc << endl;
    cout << "(a + b) + c = " << abc << endl;
    cout << "(b + c) + a = " << bca << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Which yields the output:

```
a = 1
b = -1
c = 8.8817841970012523233890533447265625e-16
a + b = 0
b + c = -1
(a + b) + c = 8.8817841970012523233890533447265625e-16
(b + c) + a = 0
```

Why is b + c = -1?

I am not getting my head around this effect of the IEEE 754 standard.

To my understanding the exponent ranges from -126 to 127. (8 bit for the biased exponent with a bias of 127.)

So 2^(-50) is representable without an issue as is 1 or -1. Neither of them are subnormal (denormalized) numbers, if I understand the standard correctly.

But why does the addition of -1 + 2^(-50) result in -1, thus the smaller number being neglected?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Compared to `-1`, `2^(-50)` is basically nothing.  A `double` only gets 15-16 digits or precision, and adding `8.9e-16` to -1 is basically a rounding error.

Comment: b+c is not 0. It specifically says `b + c = -1`

Comment: @user253751 thanks for the hint. That was a typo.

Comment: Decimal math hint: What is 1.00 + 0.00100, rounded to 3 significant digits?

Comment: What's the value of `std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon`?

Comment: [What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~david/courses/cs552/S12/handouts/goldberg-floating-point.pdf).

Comment: `c = 8.8817841970012523233890533447265625e-16` -- this is deep into false precision. A 32-bit IEEE float can represent about 6 significant digits. Everything beyond the 6th digit is noise. Attempting to print 1,000,000,000 digits is, at best, futile.

Comment: @PeteBecker: IEEE-754 single precision binary numbers do not have decimal digits at all, and thinking of them in decimal digits is a misleading model that leads to mistakes. 1.40129846432481707092372958328991613128026194187651577175706828388979108268586060148663818836212158203125•10^−45 has 105 significant digits but is represented exactly with no error, and, when printed correctly, none of its digits are noise. In particular, thinking of “noise” as part of the precision of the format rather than as arising from the computations performed interferes with correctly calculating error bounds.

Comment: @EricPostpischil -- yes, there are long decimal representations that can be exactly represented; that does not mean that every long decimal representation is meaningful. Beginners are better off thinking of hundreds of digits in a decimal representation as noise.

Comment: Beginners are better off being told that each **operation**, including conversion between decimal numerals and a binary floating-point format, may introduce some “noise” while each **value** represents one number exactly. That is how it is specified in the IEEE-754 standard, and that is the model that is needed for correct design, reasoning, analysis, and debugging of floating-point code. It is not the fact that you have a floating-point number that means some digits are “noise”; it is the fact that you have used operations that only approximate real-number arithmetic that gives you “noise.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil -- most beginners think about floating-point numbers as if they were real numbers. It can take a great deal of time and effort to introduce them to a completely different notion, and when someone is displaying 30+ digits it's much quicker to tell them "don't do that". Save the truth for later, when they're ready for it: [lies to children](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie-to-children).

Comment: It is not a difficult concept that operations round and floating-point representations are numbers.

Comment: @EricPostpischil -- I look forward to seeing your answer.

Comment: @PeteBecker: I have written many answers to floating-point questions, but that is irrelevant to whether it is beneficial to teach false statements to students and adds no merit to your position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IEEE 754 standard specifies 1 sign bit, 7 exponent bits and 24 bits for the mantissa. When performing addition, the mantissas of each number get normalized, so 2^-50 is 1 shifted right by 50 bits relative to 1. This causes it to fall outside of the 24 bit mantissa used for the result. You should try repeating your experiment with 2^-25 to prove this.

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I spent so many hours figuring out something that was - in the end - very simple. -1 + 2^(-25) also leads to -1. But -1 + 2^(-24) results in -0.999999940395355224609375, which makes sense considering your explanation.

Comment: The IEEE-754 single precision binary format has a one-bit sign, a nearly eight-bit exponent (not seven), and a 24-bit significand. This is encoded with 1 bit for the sign, eight bits for the exponent plus some additional information, and 23 bits for the primary significand encoding. (The 24th significand bit is encoded via the exponent field.)

Comment: “Significand” is the preferred term for the fraction portion of a floating-point representation. “Mantissa” is an old term for the fraction portion of a logarithm. Mantissas are logarithmic (adding to a mantissa multiplies the number represented). Significands are linear (adding to a significand adds to the number represented).

Answer (score 0):

You are using `float` which is (at least) single precision. Use `double` instead.

And `-1+9e-16` is within roundoff of `-1` in single precision.